# Silverlight alternative for ubuntu

Tags: alternative, moonlight

I'm new on Ubuntu and noticed there's no silverlight plugin for firefox. There are some alternatives I've tried, like moonlight and pipelight, they both don't seem to work on my school's website. I also don't want to use something like wine because I have some bad experiences with that.
I am using Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I dont think there is an alternative really :/

Answer (score 0):

According to this post in ubuntu forums, it seems that moonlight is the only alternative, and it isn't actively developed. sorry :(

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2029336

Comment: sadly that is true, for some specific sites like netflix there are packages that wrap a windows Firefox and silverlight in a adapted wine package to get it working for that site specific. It does the job but is not a real alternative. I believe the main problem with moonlight is that silverlight is mainly used for drm protected material and they cannot support that under Linux...

Comment: I didn't know that DRM was the problem.  Is it because the DRM won't licence to moonlight, because moonlight won't support DRM on principle, or is it some other reason?

Comment: I think that the problem is with DRM licensing to moonlight, but I am not sure, I am not really into the topic. I mainly base it on that most things without DRM more or less work(ed) but that as soon as DRM stuff was involved you where doomed. although I seem to remember hearing or reading something about it to... I think the problem for them to license the DRM stuff might be that Moonlight is open source and I am not sure how things work but you could probably get secrets out of that source code if DRM was supported?